# Pandas- set values to an empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have initialized an empty pandas dataframe that I am now trying to fill but I keep running into the same error. This is the (simplified) code I am using

```
import pandas as pd
cols = list("ABC")
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
# sett the values for the first two rows
df.loc[0:2,:] = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

On running the above code I get the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 3 to array axis with dimension 0
```

I am not sure whats causing this. I tried the same using a single row at a time and it works (`df.loc[0,:] = [1,2,3]`). I thought this should be the logical expansion when I want to handle more than one rows. But clearly, I am wrong. Whats the correct way to do this? I need to enter values for multiple rows and columns and once. I can do it using a loop but that's not what I am looking for.

Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have the columns from empty dataframe use it in dataframe constructor i.e

```
import pandas as pd
cols = list("ABC")
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]).T,columns=df.columns) 

   A  B  C
0  1  3  5
1  2  4  6
```

Well, if you want to use loc specifically then, reindex the dataframe first then assign i.e

```
arr = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]).T
df = df.reindex(np.arange(arr.shape[0]))
df.loc[0:arr.shape[0],:] = arr

   A  B  C
0  1  3  5
1  2  4  6
```

Answer (score 1):

How about adding data by index as below. You can add externally to a function as and when you receive data.

```
def add_to_df(index, data):
    for idx,i in zip(index,(zip(*data))):
        df.loc[idx]=i

#Set values for first two rows
data1 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
index1 = [0,1]
add_to_df(index1, data1)
print df
print ""

#Set values for next three rows
data2 = [[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15]]
index2 = [2,3,4]
add_to_df(index2, data2)
print df
```

**Result**

```
>>> 
     A    B    C
0  1.0  3.0  5.0
1  2.0  4.0  6.0

     A     B     C
0  1.0   3.0   5.0
1  2.0   4.0   6.0
2  7.0  10.0  13.0
3  8.0  11.0  14.0
4  9.0  12.0  15.0
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing through the documentation and some experiments, my guess is that `loc` only allows you to insert 1 key at a time. However, you can insert multiple keys first with `reindex` as @Dark shows.

> The .loc/[] operations can perform enlargement when setting a non-existent key for that axis.

http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement

Also, while you are using `loc[:2, :]`, you mean you want to select the first two rows. However, there is nothing in the empty df for you to select. There is no rows while you are trying to insert 3 rows. Thus, the message gives

```
ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 3 to array axis with dimension 0
```

BTW, `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]` will be 3 rows rather than 2.

Comment: You say dont want to use the constructor, well you are using one inside concat.

Comment: @Dark That's true... Will revise.

Comment: `they only allow you to insert 1 key at a time.` Nope we can assign multiple rows at once. But the thing is there should exist an index before assigning.  See in my answer

Comment: @Dark I think that is slightly different. I will change the wording. The part I cite is about inserting key with `loc`. What you do is you first insert keys with `reindex` methods and then insert rows.

Comment: Whats the use of use of concat over an empty dataframe, when you can get the same dataframe from the constructor.

Comment: @Dark I am imagining the whole process is dynamic. I might overthink the problem.

Comment: @Dark Thanks for the feedback. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Does this get the output you looking for:

```
   import pandas as pd
   df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2],'B':[3,4],'C':[5,6]})
```

Output :

```
    A B C
  0 1 3 5
  1 2 4 6
```

Comment: thats not the question. Once I have an empty dataframe, I want to fill it in. A lot of calculations are happening on the fly and I dont have the values beforehand