# Pandas: concise way to create/set subset or rows and columns (with MultiIndex)

Tags: python, pandas

Assume there is a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(24).reshape(4, 6), 
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list('ab'), range(3)]),
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list('xy'), range(2)]))
```

[image]

I wish to create 3 new columns `('c', 0), ('c', 1), ('c', 2)` and assign values only at indexes `('x', 0), ('x', 1)`

The result I want to get should look like this

[image]

Unfortunately writing it like this doesn't work

```
df.loc['x', 'c'] = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3)

# or

df.loc['x', [('c', 0), ('c', 1), ('c', 2)]] = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3) + 100
```

Though if I try to assign only to one new column it works:

```
df.loc['x', ('c', 0)] = np.arange(2).reshape(2, 1) + 100
```

I probably can write it using `pd.concat` and creating new dataframe with aligned `index` and `columns`, but I'm looking for a more concise way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can define the columns first

```
for id in range(3): df[('c', id)] = None
```

and then assign the values

```
df.loc['x', [('c', 0), ('c', 1), ('c', 2)]] = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3) + 100
```

or assign them even simpler, as OP pointed out

```
df.loc['x', 'c'] = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3) + 100
```

Comment: Thanks, actually, if the columns do exist, it is possible to write just `df.loc['x', 'c'] = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3) + 100`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are assigning values to **multiple** columns that do not exist at a time. You can add these columns first by reindexing the data frame.

```
new_col = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("c", 0), ("c", 1), ("c", 2)])
existing_col = df.columns
df = df.reindex(existing_col.append(new_col), axis=1)
# now you can do what you want.
df.loc['x', 'c'] = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3) + 100
```

I think `loc` will only allow you to enlarge the keys (column names here) one at a time. Thus, even though`df.loc['x', ('c', 0)] = np.arange(2).reshape(2, 1) + 100` would work. Assigning to 3 columns will fail. You can refer to my answer at [Pandas- set values to an empty dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48273907/pandas-set-values-to-an-empty-dataframe/48274281#48274281)